# How to make c++ using cin optional?

Tags: c++, cin

I want to allow user to input three strings from the keyboard. For example, firstname, lastname and middle name. The middle name is optional.

The code sample below:

```
cout << "Enter your name, first name then middle name and last name (Ex: Abby Scuito S): ";
char lastName[21], firstName[21], middleName[21];
cin >> lastName >> firstName >> middleName;
```

The problem is that it always ask for middle name input when the third block is missing which is correct based on how cin works. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make it optional. 
For example,

1. Input 1: Abby Scuito A  => Output: Abby Scuito A
2. Input 2: Abby Scuito => Output: Abby Scuito

Comment: Read the whole name using `getline`, then check if there are two names or three names in what the user entered. Then split the data up as appropriate.

Comment: @john the thing is that I have to do the filter with that string later. It is good if I can use with cin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data into a single string and separate them by space.

You may have to do some filtering, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: the thing is that I have to do the filter with that string later. It is good if I can use with cin.